# How to cleanly implement this animated slide-in component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, animation, slider

I just started out with Angular 2 and I'm struggling to implement a slide-in component cleanly.

Basically I want little slide-in icons on the right of my site and as soon as I hover them they expand.

First off, here's a [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/McXHkg).

Even though I have a fixed width of 28px for the `<li class="icon">` element, I just don't know how I can basically just "slide in" the `<ng-content select=".slide-in-text"></ng-content>` part since its width depends on its content. The `transformX()` is percentage based...

I'd be open to suggestions that are purely CSS based too. Regardless, I would *also* like to know how to do this in Angular. And I am sure it's possible to implement this without fixed widths and having to calculate things manually

Here how I use the `<slide-in>` component in my app template:

```
<nav class="nav flex-column">
  <slide-in class="mb-3">
    <span class="slide-in-icon"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></span>
    <span class="slide-in-text">Settings</span>
  </slide-in>
  <slide-in>
    <span class="slide-in-icon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
    <span class="slide-in-text">Users</span>
  </slide-in>
</nav>
```

And here's the component itself:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition, keyframes } from "@angular/animations"

@Component({
    selector: "slide-in",
    template: `
        <div id="root"
             class="bg-dark"
             (mouseenter)="mouseEnter()"
             (mouseleave)="mouseLeave()"
             [@slideInOut]="slideInOut">
            <a href="#"
               class="nav-link">
                <ul>
                    <li class="icon">
                        <ng-content select=".slide-in-icon"></ng-content>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <ng-content select=".slide-in-text"></ng-content>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </a>
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
        div#root {
            float: right;
            font-size: 14pt;
        }
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        ul li {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        li.icon {
            font-size: 20pt;
            width: 28px;
        }
        a {
            color: white;
            padding: 15px;
        }
    `],
    animations: [
        trigger("slideInOut", [
            state("out", style({
                transform: "translateX(0)"
            })),
            state("in", style({
                transform: "translateX(55%)"
            })),
            transition("in => out", animate("750ms 100ms", keyframes([
                style({transform: "translateX(-15px)", offset: 0.4}),
                style({transform: "translateX(0)", offset: 1})
            ]))),
            transition("out => in", animate("0.2s ease-in"))
        ])
    ]
})
export class SlideInComponent {
    slideInOut: string = "in";

    mouseEnter() {
        this.slideInOut = "out";
    }

    mouseLeave() {
        this.slideInOut = "in";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your meaning for setting like the jquery `$('somthing').fadeIn()`?

Comment: I know this does not answer your question but you do not have to use Angular animation. Sometimes it is more clever (because it is simple) to use things like Animate.css: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @RachChen: sorry, I'm still quite inexperienced with webdev and thought using jQuery directly was bad practice unless absolutely required, hence I didn't really look into jQuery, yet. I want a sliding effect, not a fading effect.

Comment: @Ludwig I'm going to look into that. Basically I would like to know how to solve this with Angular just to learn more about Angular. As I said, I'm open to other solutions, so thanks for the suggestion.